Filter entries in Multimap to remove duplicates
I have a Google Guava MultiMap, namely  com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap, in Java that has a lot of entries. The entries are string, like this:
URL1=URL2
URL2=URL1
URL4=URL3
URL3=URL4

As you can see, I have entries that where the key is value and the value is they. For example I have:
URL1=URL2
URL2=URL1

However my goal is to eliminate those "duplicates" and have just one result, for example:
*URL1=URL2*. How can I achieve that?
The MultiMap looks like this:
Multimap<String, String> ourToolMappings = of.finalMappings();

It might help to know which Multimap implementation you are using (which library).

Also - have you tried any approach yet?

@Hulk Hello, the package is this "import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap" and yes I have tried different approaches but I don't know which is right... I have made a mess in my head...

The entries are string and they look like this If those are entries where is the 'multi' thing? Those are the entries of a standard Map

But which one of the pair do you want to keep or does it not matter?

Post your additional details like class name as edits to your Question, not as Comments. I did so for you this time.

Your example is not a multimap. A multimap has multiple values per key. A single value per key is just a plain map.

Create an intermediate set to store already seen key value pairs and use it when filtering by taking advantage of the fact that set.add returns false when you try to add already existing elements:
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;

public class Example {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Multimap<String, String> ourToolMappings = ArrayListMultimap.create();

        ourToolMappings.put("URL1", "URL2");
        ourToolMappings.put("URL2", "URL1");
        ourToolMappings.put("URL4", "URL3");
        ourToolMappings.put("URL3", "URL4");

        System.out.println(ourToolMappings);

        Set<Map.Entry<String,String>> set = new HashSet<>(ourToolMappings.size());

        Multimap<String, String> filtered =
                ourToolMappings.entries()
                               .stream()
                               .filter(x -> set.add(Map.entry(x.getKey(), x.getValue())) &&
                                            set.add(Map.entry(x.getValue(), x.getKey())))
                               .collect(ImmutableListMultimap.toImmutableListMultimap(
                                       Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

        System.out.println(filtered);
    }
}


Well, this does not pertain to multimap but it should work.
Just iterate over the existing map, adding the entry, followed by attempting to remove the value as a key.  Non duplicates will be preserved and order does not matter.
Generate some data
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i+=2) {
    String key = "URL"+i;
    String value = "URL" + (i+1);
    map.put(key, value);
    map.put(value,key);
}
map.put("URL9","URL10");

Create a new filtered map
Map<String,String> result = new HashMap<>();
for (Entry<String,String> e : map.entrySet()) {
    result.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    result.remove(e.getValue());
}

result.entrySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);

prints
URL5=URL6
URL3=URL4
URL1=URL2
URL9=URL10
URL7=URL8

